# Google sheets queries with IF statments

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to write this query for a while and have tried a few sites but not explain really how to use the IF statement.

So I have data in columns that are people scores for films

|  | Jim | Jack | Fred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Film 1 | 6 | 6 | 2 |
| Film 2 | 7 | 8 | 5 |
| Film 3 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
| ... |  |  |  |

for example and i want a query that when i select a cell with a name in it it will return the scores for that person (make top ten and scores by film genera / person etc.)

So I have this query I know the syntax is not correct I have tried many ways and cant get it to work. (E18 is the cell I with a pick list of the names)

```
=Query(Sheet1!A4:D,"select A & IF(E18=”Jim”, select B order by B desc Limit 10"")")
```

What I want to do is when I select a name then it returns the top 10 films for that user + the scores

Any help greatly received.

Thankyou

aaron

Comment: You will need to share a link to a spreadsheet with a sample of realistic data. It is not clear from your post where your data is, where you want the results, how/where you are indicating the name, etc.

Comment: If you use `IF()` then you have to write condition for each actor. Rather use `MATCH()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume you will select actor name in `F1` cell (as per my attached screenshot). They try below `QUERY()` formula.

```
=QUERY(A2:D4,"select A, " & CHAR(MATCH(F1,A1:D1,0)+64) & " order by " & CHAR(MATCH(F1,A1:D1,0)+64) & " desc limit 10")
```

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant thank you so much for the help. Exactly what i needed.